# How do you specify an alternative folder to the asset folder at build time

Tags: android, ant, android-assets

I'm in the process of setting up a build system for android, ios, and windows platform that shares the same code.

For the android piece of the build, I want to have this shared code in the assets folder without actually having the code in the folder because it also needs to be used by the other pieces of the build as well.

the folder structure would look something like this

```
[android]
    [assets]
        [source code]
[ios]
[windows]
[source code]
```

I could not find any config that I can change in either the build.xml or the AndroidManifest.xml to specify using another folder instead of the assets folder.
How do you specify to `ant` to package the `[source code]` folder on the first level into the assets folder when you do a `ant debug`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the debug is just another ant target.

when the Android SDK is installed, the build script for android is also installed under the path:

```
<Android SDK>\tools\ant
```

under the Other Properties section, there's a property like follows

```
<property name="asset.dir" value="assets" />
```

which seems to use relative pathing based on the location of the build.xml in your project

if I copy the line and paste it in the build.xml in my own project, and modify it to something like:

```
<property name="asset.dir" value="..\[source code]" />
```

then the build goes through successfully pulling the correct content into the assets folder during the build.